# Cocoa Console Application - property not found on object of type

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So I am quite new on OC programming, I come from Front-end background (i.e. HTML/CSS/JavaScript ...), so I understand basic concepts of programming :)

Basically I created a console application, with a simple **FooClass**.

**FooClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FooClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *username;

- (NSString *) username;
- (void) setUsername:(NSString *)username;

@end
```

**FooClass.m**

```
#import "FooClass.h"

@implementation FooClass

@synthesize username = _username;

- (instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *) username
{
    return _username;
}

- (void) setUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    _username = username;
}

@end
```

And in the main.m file, where the app bootstraps.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "FooClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        FooClass *foo = [[FooClass alloc] init];
        foo.username = @"a";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

XCode tells me that it cannot find property *username* on object of type **FooClass**. And I don't really have idea about it. Any one could help?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late in posting the answer. Here are few things that you should consider.

1. Since you have a `property username`. You are not required to create methods for setters and getters. The compiler will create them for you. Simply remove the two statements.
2. No need to `synthesize`  in `.m` as well.
3. Instead of `#include` use `#import`. `import` takes only one copy even if you try to add the file(s) directly or indirectly from other files as compared to `include`.